# Including .css files in twig/volt

Tags: html, css, frontend, volt

Is that possible to include a css files in volt templates, just like another volt file? Something like this?

```
{% include 'style.css' %}
```

If not - why?

Answer (score 0):

Afaik it's not possible. Well, it is, if you want your css file as a plain text. And if that file is located within your views directory. But there is no need to do that (other then plain text, which i assume is not what you want). You can include css just like in any other regular html.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
```